# I have a query that uses 'WHERE [value] IN (X);' does adding more values to the IN increase runtime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that uses a 'WHERE [value] in (X);' for example:

```
SELECT
      [col1]
    , [col2]
    , [value]
FROM Table 
WHERE [value] IN ('X','Y')
```

My question is, if I were to add a 'Z' to the IN, will this increase the query runtime?

The problem I have with testing this is that only our production environment contains enough data to where this would be relevant; there's not enough data in our testing environments to make the difference clear. I also can't freely test this in production because of the size of data involved, so I'd like to have a theoretical idea of what to expect before I start trying test queries.

The values in the IN clause will all be text values; no numerics. [value] column is of VARCHAR2 type.

Comment: If you start to worry about that (probably because the list of values can be very long)  then you should change the query to a JOIN instead of using IN()

Comment: @juergend you mean he should be joining like that? `INNER JOIN (VALUES ('X'), ('Y')) AS T([value] ON ...`? If so, i don't think it would make a difference. SQL Server would compile it the way it wants anyway.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: No, I think the values come from somewhere. And if that is another table then JOIN against that table and if not then put them in a table and JOIN against that.

Comment: Do you have any Index on `Value` column

Answer (score 1):

> if I were to add a 'Z' to the IN, will this increase the query runtime?

Yes. Even with an index, this new value means a new lookup and probably more data to load.

Also, even with an index, the optimizer may choose to execute a `FULL TABLE SCAN` instead of an `INDEX SCAN`, mainly when your `IN` values are expected to be in most of the rows or if your table has few data.

Generally, you should believe in the optimizer. If it seems too slow, you could try to split the `IN` values in separated queries and `UNION ALL` the results. Probably, the optimizer will execute an `INDEX SCAN` for each query. I can't confirm this change will improve the query runtime. I'm only talking about change a `FULL TABLE SCAN` to an `INDEX SCAN`.

Answer (score 1):

Some work needs to be done for each value in the `IN` clause.  The one exception is if all rows match `'X'` and `'Y'`, then there is no extra work to be done.  In one borderline case, the only additional work is a microsecond or so for the compiler to process the slightly larger query.

Is this extra work important?  Probably not.  It is not going to increase the run-time of the query by 50%.  The timing for the query will be dominated by reading the data pages, not the comparison.  Of course, the list could get big enough where the difference is noticeable, but I don't think that two items to three will make much of a difference.  And, if there is a difference, it is probably because more rows are returned.

Some databases (but not SQL Server as far as I know) will optimize the `IN` lookup by creating a binary tree structure for constant elements.  If SQL Server did that, then the additional items would be even less of an issue.  You could emulate this behavior by putting the items into a temporary table with an index to maximize performance.

My guess, though, is that this question is motivated by premature optimization.  Understanding how queries perform is -- of course -- very important to getting an application to work well.  It is unlikely that a small increase in the number of items in an `IN` list is going to make a whole lot of difference.